# How can I distinguish an instrument from a sound?

Tags: audio

I just saw a paper by Cornell reconstructing faces from sound. But I am more interested in the timbre. It might be attacked with AI, but is there an easier way? For example, is instrument a going to be on a different range than instrument b.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, instruments are going to have overlapping frequency content. IDK the specific algorithms for isolating instruments--I've heard they do exist. I would think that a big element is not just tracking all the harmonics and frequency content, but looking for correspondences in volume changes or frequency changes of the different frequencies, in order to determine which frequencies should be grouped together as a single instrument. Since instruments often play the same notes at the same time, this would be no mean feat. If you are a beginner with digital signal processing, can I recommend "The Scientists and Engineers Guide to DSP" by Steve Smith? (Free download, good book on the fundamental knowledge needed to tackle such a project.)